# ¿Alguien me puede ayudar con el algoritmo de ordenamiento por seleccion?

Tags: javascript

Tengo este codigo:

```js
function num(arr) {
        var leng = arr.length,
            i, x;
    for( i = 0; i < leng; i++) {
        for( x = i + 1; x < leng; x++) {
            console.log(arr.toString())
            if (arr[i] > arr[x]) {
                a(arr, i, x);
                //console.log(arr)
            }
            
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
function a(arr, f, s) {
    var temp = arr[f];
    arr[f] = arr[s];
    arr[s] = temp;
   // console.log(arr)
}
document.getElementById("alg").innerHTML = num([8, 5, 2, 6, 9, 3, 1, 4, 0, 7]);
```

```html
<h2 id="alg"></h2>
```

Al ejecutarlo, lo hace de forma que ordena el primer numero que encuentra, así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y necesito que el algoritmo recorra todo el array asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema es que no estás implementando correctamente el [algoritmo de ordenamiento por selección](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordenamiento_por_selecci%C3%B3n)

El pseudocódigo es este:

```
para i=0 hasta n-1
    mínimo = i;
    para j=i+1 hasta n
        si lista[j] < lista[mínimo] entonces
            mínimo = j /* (!) */
        fin si
    fin para
    intercambiar(lista[i], lista[mínimo])
fin para
```

Tienes que inicializar un valor mínimo (inicialmente será cero) con el que comparar los valores de tu `array`:

```js
function num(arr) {       
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let min=i;
        for(let x = i + 1; x < arr.length; x++) {            
            if (arr[min] > arr[x]) {              
                min = x;
            }            
        }
        a(arr, i, min);
    }
    return arr;
}
function a(arr, f, s) {
    console.log(arr.toString());
    var temp = arr[f];
    arr[f] = arr[s];
    arr[s] = temp;    
}

document.getElementById("alg").innerHTML = num([8, 5, 2, 6, 9, 3, 1, 4, 0, 7]);
```

```html
<h2 id="alg"></h2>
```

**Edito**: Añado un ejemplo utilizando [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Destructuring_assignment). Con ello te ahorras la variable `temp` y la función `a`

```js
function num(arr) {       
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let min=i;
        for(let x = i + 1; x < arr.length; x++) {            
            if (arr[min] > arr[x]) {              
                min = x;
            }            
        }
        console.log(arr.toString());
        [arr[min],arr[i]] = [arr[i],arr[min]] 
    }
    return arr;
}
document.getElementById("alg").innerHTML = num([8, 5, 2, 6, 9, 3, 1, 4, 0, 7]);
```

```html
<h2 id="alg"></h2>
```